# How to find the globally defined analyzer name in Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

When searching in Elastic search, by default, the globally defined analyzer is used.  How can I find out what this analyzer is ?  We are using a Elastic search saas provider and I thus want to find out what the setting is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, Elasticsearch will use the `Standard Analyzer` as default if none other is specified upon index creation.